# Ordering a collection in mvc which is part of a DTO or viewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a DTO or view model which is linked to collection of another DTO..

```
var  eventStatsViewModel = new StatsViewModel();
var eventStatDetails = new List<EventStartsDetails>();
eventStatDetails = populateStats(Id);
eventStatsViewModel.EventStatDetails.AddRange(eventStatDetails);              
eventStatsViewModel.EventStatDetails.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
```

In the above case order by descending doesnot work fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OrderByDescending` will return new object. You are not assigning the returned object to your view model property. Please assign it.

Comment: ofcourse this was the reason.. silly me..

Answer (score 1):

Because you're not assign result of OrderByDescending to `eventStatsViewModel.EventStatDetails`

```
eventStatsViewModel.EventStatDetails= eventStatsViewModel.EventStatDetails.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
```

Comment: this was helpful.. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

[OrderByDescending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending(v=vs.110).aspx) returns new object. So, you must assign result to EventStatDetails:

```
eventStatsViewModel.EventStatDetails = eventStatsViewModel.EventStatDetails.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();
```